# How to check if an aix system is up to date (updates & security fixes)

Tags: aix

I m trying to write some test scripts with inspec 
Is there any linux commands to check if an aix server has updates and has security fixes ???

Comment: You want *Linux* commands to check an *AIX* server? In what way do you access the AIX system? Do you have a NIM server?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to determine AIX patch level (Technology Level/Service Pack), to do that you can run:

```
# oslevel -s
```

Also always check for firmware versions:

```
# lsmcode -c
```

Dont forget about HMC:

```
# lshmc -V
```

And VIOS:

```
# ioslevel
```

In any case if you are managing Power Systems with AIX i would highly recommend Fix Level Recommendation Tool -> [FLRT](https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/set2/flrt/home) This is online software that recommends fixes and patches. Nowadays it has tons of useful information including ready to run scripts for inspecting your system for known vulnerabilities -> [flrtvc](https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/set2/flrt/sas?page=flrtvc)